# Android Upload Multiple Images after capturing from Camera

Tags: java, android, retrofit, android-camera, android-camera-intent

Guys I need some help with an android app that has to upload image to server, ***the requirement is to upload multiple images after capturing from the camera(restrict user from attaching from gallery/storage)***. Whats the best way to implement this? using camera intent and retrofit or are there any other methods that you could suggest?

Scenario- user starts a task in my application-> directs to a reports activity page with text input fields and camera button. Is there a way to launch the camera->capture(ex:5 images)->after capture return back to activity and upload using upload button (or upload in background service).

Any suggestions recommendations are welcome

Thank you

Comment: `. Is there a way to launch the camera->capture(ex:5 images)` No.

Comment: @blackapps____ ok